# Is 1.5 hours of a layover time in Dubai practical?

Tags: transit, layovers, dubai, emirates

I plan to fly from Bangalore (India) to Dubai and then to San Francisco, all on the Emirates Airline. I have an option of a 1.5 hour layover in Dubai.

I'm wondering if this is sufficient time to make my connection. Are transiting passengers required to clear customs/security in Dubai ? Any information on potential causes of delay is appreciated.

Comment: If it's all Emirates, you don't need to worry - if you miss your connection because your incoming flight is late, it's their fault, and they'll re-seat you on another flight.  For the transit question - we have a LOT of transit questions in Dubai on here, have you had a look? What citizenship are you?

Comment: If you're flying through a place as gorgeous as Dubai, why not stay for a few hours to explore around :o

Comment: Maybe unrelated but Emirates has its own terminal in Dubai so their passengers get processed much faster. If your connecting flight is also Emirates, then you will be even better off.

Comment: You (and your carry-on luggage) will go through x-ray screening before being led to the transit area. Other than this, there are no further formalities.

Answer (score 14):

**It's fine**.  The minimum connecting time for Emirates-Emirates flights is 75 minutes — sorry, can't find an authoritative source for this, but if you booked your flights through Emirates, they'll only offer legal connections anyway.

If your incoming flight is on time, you'll make it.  If it's delayed and you miss the connection, Emirates will put you on another flight.

Comment: +1 for this. The only thing I would add is that if your incoming flight is late, you will see agents at your arriving flight's gate calling out the destination. They will take you to a transit desk, where you will get either [a] rebooked on the next flight and a voucher for a meal if there is a large delay or [b] hotel accommodation, a meal voucher, a transit visa and a booking on your next flight or [c] in rare cases, they may book you on another carrier. Either way, you are guaranteed to arrive at your destination.

Answer (score 12):

[jpatokal answer](https://travel.stackexchange.com/a/42509/1488) is correct. But I'll add that you will need to go through a security screening in Dubai (not immigration) and your luggage should be checked through.

In my experience it is certainly feasible to get from gate to gate in about 45 minutes. I also noticed staff standing outside the security screening trying to flag down passengers for flights that were leaving very soon. Presumably to help them get through quickly.

Another concern here is, if the inbound flight is delayed, how long until the next flight out to your destination? If that route is only flown once a day, you may want to consider if it is worth the risk.

In your case, this route is only flown once a day.

Answer (score 2):

I traveled this route twice (Hyd-Dubai-US) with emirates. Even they give 1 hr 30 lay over when you book the ticket, but they will change it to three hours layover. You should get a notification email from emirates before you travel. This happened to me twice. And yes 1.5 hours is enough is ideal conditions but not always.

Comment: You certainly can't count on that happening, plus the OP is flying from Bangalore to SF, not Hyderabad to "US".