# Additional flight appeared on my booking with Emirates

Tags: air-travel, bookings, emirates

I have booked return flights with Emirates from Manchester to Kathmandu (with a connection in Dubai) for Apr/May 2020. So it looks like Manchester > Dubai, Dubai > Kathmandu and then Kathmandu > Dubai, Dubai > Manchester.

I recently revisited the Emirates website to update some of my details and went to manage the booking. My eTicket contains details for the original flights I booked, there and back. However, when I visit the 'seat selection' page, there appears to be an additional flight going from Dubai to Kathmandu. So I'm now seeing Manchester > Dubai, Dubai > Kathmandu (which is all fine) and then Kathmandu > Dubai, Kathmandu > Dubai, Dubai > Manchester. Why are there now two Kathmandu > Dubai flights? The additional flight is the same day but is some eight hours earlier at a time that won't work for me.

My friend who has booked onto the same return flight has experienced the same.

Comment: What did Emirates say when you contacted them to ask about this?

Comment: @Traveller It's been a couple of days and no response, which is why I'm here!

Comment: Have you checked if your original flight still shows up when you are doing a search on the same dates? It could be possible they are in the process of changing schedules and reassigning you to another flight, though in general they would contact you about this. Is you contact information up to date? Have you checked your junk mailbox?

Comment: @jcaron Neither myself or my friend have received any emails about any schedule changes. I did just spend 30 minutes on the phone to somebody though working out what had happened - I'll write something up in the answers.

Answer (score 3):

After finding time to ring Emirates, I eventually got my answer!

There had been a minor schedule change on one of the returning flights, which meant the connecting time in Dubai no longer met the Emirates minimum connecting time of 75 minutes ([which I read about on this SE question](https://travel.stackexchange.com/questions/42508/is-1-5-hours-of-a-layover-time-in-dubai-practical)). For this reason, we had been automatically moved onto the considerably earlier flight.

Looks as though the online booking/eTicket not updating may have been a technical issue though (alongside the lack of emails informing us about the schedule changes), as this needed to be updated manually by a member of staff.